# How to Display category/tag specific content

Tags: wordpress

I want to display some content depending on the category of the post.
i mean
if one reading a post in the category 'Travel' I want to show some tips related to that
if in category "games", some other content.
I need this preferably in the sidebar.
Is there any plugin? If not, is it possible to achieve with the help of some modification

Comment: There are a lot of solutions to this, so providing a direct answer isn't really possible. A quick Google comes up with a lot of methods as well, have you tried anything so far?

The most straight forward was is to do it programatically in your category.php/archive.php files based on a conditional. `get_query_var('cat');` will give you the current category ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Just replace "CATEGORYNAME" with your category name whereever you want:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=CATEGORYNAME&showposts=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  // do whatever you want
?>
<b><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

        $args2 = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'cat' => 4,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_parent' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true
        );
        $homepage_content = get_posts($args2);

        foreach ($homepage_content as $key => $value) {
            echo "<h2>" . $value->post_title . "</h2>";
            echo $value->post_content;
            $post_id = $value->ID;
        }

?>
```

Here just pass ID of Category in cat argument.

```
For more reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
```

-
Thanks